# make error as: unrecognized option '-mcpu=arm1176jzf-s'

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile some C to run on a friendlyARM for days now without any luck, i think im close but getting this error:

```
kevin@kevin-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/makef$ make
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c -o obj/main.o main.c -I./
as: unrecognized option '-mcpu=arm1176jzf-s'
make: *** [obj/main.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone know how to what this error means and how to fix it?

steps i have tried:

1

```
touch *.*
make clean
make 
(error as: unrecognized option '-mcpu=arm1176jzf-s)
```

2

```
touch *.*
make clean
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-l
(error as: unrecognized option '-mcpu=arm1176jzf-s)
```

the Makefile :

```
IDIR =./
CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
LDIR =./

LIBS=-lgd -lrt

_DEPS = main.h Makefile
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = main.o serial.o fb.o menu_main.o timer.o cmdin.o buzzer.o statemachine.o inout.o network.o text_file_input.o text_file_input_oven.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

Comment: can you please reformulate ? There is no question in the post.

Comment: You are invoking a makefile that attempts to use a custom toolchain `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` to compile the program.  This appears to invoke the assembler, passing in `-mcpu=arm1176jzf-s`, and you do not have the complete toolchain installed.  Since you are cross-compiling you may have to build the toolchain yourself

Answer (score 0):

It means the version of `gcc` that you have installed does not understand the option `-mcpu=arm1176jzf-s`

Either you have an older version of `gcc` which does not accept that option, or you have a version of `gcc` that has cross compiling support turned off.

Comment: How can I check if gcc's cross compiling support turned off.